# What has been the worst return ultra-short-term funds have delivered?

Tags: india, mutual-funds, debt

What's the worst performance any investor has seen? A 1% drop in value? 2%?

I know that liquid funds have seen as much as a [0.4%](http://capitalmind.in/2013/07/liquid-funds-navs-fall-for-the-first-time-in-5-years/) drop in value in a single day. Since ultra-short-term funds are riskier, I expect them to have had a greater drop in value. Do you know what the worst performance was?

I know that one ultra-short-term fund has had to [limit](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-others/jp-morgan-amcs-redemption-crisis-dont-liquidate-holdings-in-a-hurry/) redemptions at one point. Have there been other instances of that happening?

Comment: what is your definition of 'ultra-short-term'? 0.4% in a liquid fund is not very much, are you referring to money market liquid funds?

Comment: Ultra short term funds are a common category of funds in India — they invest in high-quality debt like CDs and commercial paper with short tenures (but generally longer than 2 months). We don't have anything called "money market liquid funds" here, and I don't know which fund type in India corresponds to that, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're counting one-off events, the recent JP Morgan affair led to a 5-6% drop in the two funds that got into trouble. This article has details: http://vro.in/s28769

Otherwise, on Value Research Online, each fund's snapshot page lists the worst (and best) month, quarter and year. Unfortunately, you have to open each fund from the category listing (https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/fundSelector/default.asp?exc=susp%2Cdir%2Cclose&cat=2) to look at the best-worst.